# Parse a nested List lists and Dicts in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested-lists

I'm using the google maps api python client to get geocoding data. The api returns a list that appears to be a list of lists and dicts. Here is an sample of one result.

```
[[{'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Liverpool',
 'short_name': 'Liverpool',
 'types': ['locality', 'political']},
{'long_name': 'Merseyside',
 'short_name': 'Merseyside',
 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
{'long_name': 'England',
 'short_name': 'England',
 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
{'long_name': 'United Kingdom',
 'short_name': 'GB',
 'types': ['country', 'political']}]
```

It goes on for a while and then a new list starts with address_components a little ways down. In the middle of each result is `'location':{'lat':xxx, 'lng':xxx},`

```
'location': {'lat': 53.4083714, 'lng': -2.9915726},
'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE',
'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 53.503907, 'lng': -2.8129382},
 'southwest': {'lat': 53.3204478, 'lng': -3.0191793}}}
```

I'm trying to get that value for `'lat'` and `lng`.

I've tried parsing this in a couple number of ways. For example:

```
example = [[{'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Liverpool',
 'short_name': 'Liverpool',
 'types': ['locality', 'political']},
{'long_name': 'Merseyside',
 'short_name': 'Merseyside',
 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
{'long_name': 'England',
 'short_name': 'England',
 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
{'long_name': 'United Kingdom',
 'short_name': 'GB',
 'types': ['country', 'political']}]
```

I tried parsing like so:

`for x in example[i]:
    for t in x:
        print(t)`

this returns:

```
address_components
formatted_address
geometry
place_id
types
```

Now, my `lat` and `lng` are in that `geometry` like so:

```
'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 53.503907, 'lng': -2.8129382},
 'southwest': {'lat': 53.3204478, 'lng': -3.0191793}}
```

But if I try to extend my for loop to look like this:

`for x in source_ll[i]:
    for t in x:
        for z in t:
            print(z)`

It outputs:
`a
d
d
r
e
s
s
_
c
o
m
p
o
n
e
n
t
s
f
o
r
m
a`

and so on. Which are just the strings that make up what was returned from `for t in x`.

**Update**
I tried:

`for x in example[i]:
    for t in x:
        for value in ['geometry']:
            print(value)`

But this returns
`geometry` n times.

I just want to get `53.4083714` and `-2.9915726`.

What I realize is that I need your help!!

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of your attempt to implement this.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe. This question forced me to go back and look at my approach. I included in the main text the most fruitful of my attempts. I feel like I'm zeroing in on this but can crack it.

Comment: `for t in x` gives you the *keys*; read up on dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe I'm familiar with dictionaries. My issue is that the particular way in which this set of dictionaries is nested in a list is beyond my abilities to parse. That's why I'm asking the community to help with this. When I attempt to access the keys, everything is mangled which means I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#for key1, value1 in target_query.items():
        try:
            for entities in value1:
                if isinstance(entities, dict):
                    for key2, value2 in entities.items():
                        if isinstance(value2, dict):
                            for key3, value3 in value2.items():
                                if isinstance(value3, dict):
                                    for key4, value4 in value3.items():

                                        if isinstance(value4, dict):

                                            x = value4.get('lat')
                                            x = str(x)
                                            y = value4.get('lng')
                                            y = str(y)`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for c in some_string: print(c)`, you just print `some_string` a character at a time, each on its own line.  Instead, you want something like the following, where the processing of geometry entries is based on your example above.

```
        if t == 'geometry':
            bnd = t['bounds']
            ne = bnd['northeast']
            sw = bnd['southwest']
            [print('ne', ne['lat'], ne['lng'], 'sw', sw['lat'], sw['lng']
```

Comment: Thank you! An interesting error was thrown in response to this:
`TypeError ...
      2     for t in x:
      3         if t == 'geometry':
----> 4             bnd = t['bounds']
      5             ne = bnd['northeast']
      6             sw = bnd['southwest']

TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: The index of any sequence must indeed be an int.  But the key to a dict can be and often is a string.  Based on the geometry example, I expected everything subscripted in my snippet should be a dict.  But I suspected you might have to adjust to your actual data.  It is a complicated structure that is hard to ask questions about.